# How can I make a LDAP query that returns only groups having OU=Groups from all levels?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

If I am looking for all `Groups`, I get too much garbage.

If I try to narrow down the base, I get too few.

Here is an example:

```
CN=A Team,OU=Groups,OU=Americas,DC=example,DC=com
CN=B TEAM,OU=Groups,OU=EMEA,DC=example,DC=com
CN=C Team,OU=Legacy Groups,DC=example,DC=com
CN=D Team,OU=Groups,OU=Bangalore,OU=APAC,DC=example,DC=com
CN=E Team,OU=Common Groups,DC=example,DC=com
```

I am looking for a LDAP `filter` that returns A B D E (without C) - mainly the logic would be get me all groups that do have last `OU=Groups` or `OU=Common Groups`

My current search is using:

```
 Search base: CN=Users,DC=citrite,DC=net
 Filter: (objectCategory=Group)
```

Comment: Have you tried a filter something like `(&(objectCategory=Group)(distinguishedName=*OU=Groups*))` ?

Comment: Distinguished names (DNs) are not attributes, they are collections of one or more relative distinguished names and cannot be used in filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, on Microsoft Active Directory is impossible to do this in a single search, that's because AD is not fully LDAP compatible.

LDAP-compliant servers support an `extensible-match` filter which provides the necessary
filtering. From [RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5):

> If the dnAttributes field is set to TRUE, the match is additionally
> applied against all the AttributeValueAssertions in an entry's
> distinguished name, and it evaluates to TRUE if there is at least
> one attribute or subtype in the distinguished name for which the
> filter item evaluates to TRUE.  The dnAttributes field is present
> to alleviate the need for multiple versions of generic matching
> rules (such as word matching), where one applies to entries and
> another applies to entries and DN attributes as well.

Note that the *extensible-match* filter technique only works with LDAP-compliant servers,
of which AD is not one.

For example, I added the following entries to a server:

```
dn: ou=legacy groups,o=training
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: legacy groups

dn: ou=common groups,o=training
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: common groups

dn: ou=groups,o=training
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: cn=a,ou=common groups,o=training
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: uid=user.0,ou=people,o=training
cn: a

dn: cn=b,ou=groups,o=training
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: uid=user.0,ou=people,o=training
cn: b

dn: cn=c,ou=legacy groups,o=training
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: uid=user.0,ou=people,o=training
cn: c
```

Examine the filter in the following search after the above entries were added:

```
ldapsearch --propertiesFilePath ds-setup/11389/ldap-connection.properties \
    --baseDN o=training \
    --searchScope sub '(|(ou:dn:=groups)(ou:dn:=common groups))' 1.1

dn: ou=common groups,o=training

dn: cn=a,ou=common groups,o=training

dn: ou=groups,o=training

dn: cn=b,ou=groups,o=training
```

Note that `ou=common groups`, `ou=groups`, and their subordinates are returned, but not
`ou=legacy groups` and subordinates.

*This example uses the modern syntax of the ldapsearch command line tool. If the user is
utilizing the legacy OpenLDAP version of ldapsearch, the parameters to the command line tool are
somewhat different, but that does not matter. What matters is the filter.*

Comment: Thanks Terry, before posting the question I tried something quite similar, with `ou:dn:=groups` but when I put this I never get any results. I am querying a Microsoft Active Directory, so I suppose I have no control over the dnAttributes field - in fact I have no idea how to even see its value.