# How do I make a LDAP search on OU on Microsoft Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I tried to return LDAP search that should return me all entries that do have `OU=groups` on an active directory by I do not get the expected results (usually I get nothing).

Filter: `(ou:dn:=groups)`

I know that searching on DN is not possible by normal means, still what is the correct way of getting this information in a filer, one that would work with Active Directory.

Reference:

- [How can I make a LDAP query that returns only groups having OU=Groups from all levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035030/how-can-i-make-a-ldap-query-that-returns-only-groups-having-ou-groups-from-all-l#comment12846551_10035030)
- http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEV/How+to+write+LDAP+search+filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that in one search. You can first look for all organizational units of the name OU=groups, and then make a search for each OU.

It exists [ExtensibleMatch](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) that allow what you want to do, but it's [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223241%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) in Active-Directory.

Here is the reference form [Microsft supported Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That's true, AD is not LDAP-compliant. My answer to the posters question from earlier was dependent on a standards-compliant LDAP server. Another alternative is to add a distinguishing attribute to the entries required for the search -- a little more work either way (multiple searches or adding attributes), but that is the price to pay for using a non-compliant server. Unfortunately, many organizations do not have the luxury of using something other than AD.